# Showing this piecewise series is not Cesaro summable

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cesaro-summable

I have been asked to show that the series a_{n}=

\begin{matrix}
\frac{n+1}{2}&if&n&is&odd&  & \\ 
-\frac{n}{2}&if&n&is&even &  & 
\end{matrix}

is not (C,1) Cesaro summable.

Not quite sure how to go about doing this so any help, hints, or process description will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the sequence starts at $n=1$, let us obtain an expression for the partial sums
$$S_k = \sum_{n=1}^{k}a_n$$
If $k$ is even, then 
$$\begin{aligned}
S_k &= \sum_{m=1}^{k/2}(a_{2m-1} + a_{2m}) \\
&= \sum_{m=1}^{k/2}\left( \frac{(2m-1)+1}{2} - \frac{2m}{2}  \right) \\
&= 0
\end{aligned}$$
If $k$ is odd, then
$$S_k = S_{k-1} + a_k = 0 + \frac{k+1}{2} = \frac{k+1}{2}$$
The first few $S_k$ are therefore
$$1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, \ldots$$
The sum of the first $2n-1$ of these partial sums is simply $1 + 2 + \cdots + n = n(n+1)/2$. In other words,
$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n-1}S_k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
and therefore the average of the first $2n-1$ partial sums is
$$\frac{1}{2n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{2n-1}S_k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2(2n-1)}$$
which diverges to $\infty$ as $n \to \infty$.